# Remove all variations of same number in array using php

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array that I read from a file, and I'm trying to remove all the possibilities from that array but keep the originating number.

```php
$n = Array
(
    [0] => 050
    [1] => 051
    [2] => 052
    [3] => 501
    [4] => 054
    [5] => 150
    [6] => 061
    [7] => 062
    [8] => 510
    [9] => 064
)
```

In my code, I loop the file into an array, and then I have a function called combo, which gives me all possible combinations of that number ex: 051 can be 150, 510, 501.

My combo function is as follows:

```php
function combo($num){
    
    $a = array();
    $n_s = str_split($num);
    
    
    // 5 8 2
    
    // first combo
    $c1 = $n_s[0] . '' . $n_s[2] . '' . $n_s[1];
    $c2 = $n_s[1] . '' . $n_s[0] . '' . $n_s[2];
    $c3 = $n_s[1] . '' . $n_s[2] . '' . $n_s[0];
    $c4 = $n_s[2] . '' . $n_s[0] . '' . $n_s[1];
    $c5 = $n_s[2] . '' . $n_s[1] . '' . $n_s[0];
    

    array_push($a, $c1, $c2, $c3, $c4, $c5);
    
    return($a);
    
}


function mirror($n){
    
    $m = array("0" => "5", "1" => "6", "2" => "7", "3" => "8", "4" => "9", "5" => "0", "6" => "1", "7" => "2", "8" => "3", "9" => "4");
    
    
    $n_s = str_split($n);
    
    $f = $m[$n_s[0]] . '' . $m[$n_s[1]] . '' . $m[$n_s[2]];

    return $f;

}
```

```php
foreach($n as $v){
        echo $v . '<br>';

        $t = combo($v);
        
        foreach($t as $vs){
            unset($n[$vs]);
        }
}
```

So what I am looking for as a result would return the original array, keeping the 051, and removing the 501, 150, 510 variations. This will work under a loop for 250 numbers. If my math is right, it should return a final array approximately with 25 numbers.

Any help is appreciated, I can't seem to get this right, and I'm missing something.

Comment: I'd probably apply a callback to "sort" each digit in an ascending nature (eg end up with multiple 015) then apply an array unique keeping the indexes to retain the first instance of that combination, the use the indexes to extract the original numbers from the original array.

Comment: is you `combo()` function small enough to post here?

Comment: @Scuzzy I updated the OP to show the combo function. But there's also a mirror function as well.

Comment: The idea is to take the list, clean out it's raw combinations, (eg: 510, 501, 105, 150) and then take that array, and then run it's mirrors through. So for example, 051 can also be 551, 506, 650, 600, and so on. When it's done, it should be left with only around 25 numbers. I'm trying to write this code so I don't have to do it manually.

Comment: My only suggestion is to take your starting number, and create an array of all the combinations you DON'T want and then filter them out of your end product. I'm having a hard time picturing how this code is now used now that "mirror" function has appeared in your code.

Comment: @Scuzzy The mirror function is used to find the mirror to a number you input to the function. For example, you throw 854, the function str_split() the number and then finds each respective mirror number and then reassembles the number and returns it.

Comment: @MrTechie Please [edit] your question to present a sufficiently challenging and representative [mcve].  Otherwise, we cannot be confident that we are giving correct/robust/reliable advice.

Comment: @MrTechie I can see what it does, I just don't understand the what problem its trying to solve, but ultimatly that's up to the code you're trying to create :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've taken the idea of converting `051,501,150,510` all into `015` so that duplicates can be filtered out, then using `array_intersect_key` to take the keys of what is left and use that to return values from the original array.

```
// Converted to string since you want to keep your leading zero?
$array = [ '050','051','052','501','054','150','061','062','510','064' ];

// sort each digit in each array item so we can apply array_unique to the entire set of numbers to remove duplicates
$reduced = array_unique( array_map( function( $n ){
    $number = str_split( $n );
    sort($number);
    return implode( '', $number );
}, $array ) );

// Use the keys from this new array to extract the values from the original array
$output = array_intersect_key( $array, $reduced );

// done!
print_r( $output );
```

Returns

```
Array
(
    [0] => 050
    [1] => 051
    [2] => 052
    [4] => 054
    [6] => 061
    [7] => 062
    [9] => 064
)
```

Comment: Note this will fail if you start to use integers, as the leading zero is redundant, how do you want to deal with `0401` vs `401` etc?

Comment: Thanks you! Basically it's 000-999. Also, I'm a bit confused how I can put this through a loop. I need to do this with every number in the originating array.

Comment: Feed your entire crafted array through this code and you'll get the first for each unique combinations.

Comment: Perfect, I think I see it now. What was throwing me off was I was expecting the array key count to decrease, but it's not, it's just removing the key=>val and keeping the rest.

Comment: @MrTechie to reindex final array you can use `array_values()`

Comment: @anant-alive-to-die Thank you! I was hoping this would be slightly different, because I have to re-process this list again and remove it's mirrored variations. For example, 051 can be 506, and all those possible combos (eg: 650, 605, 600, etc) Basically there should be around 25 numbers left in it's "raw" form, all the rest is fluff. 25 x 10 variations is 250 numbers, which is the original array count.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see any way to more simply the sort the digits than splitting, sorting, then imploding.

Beyond that, I suppose using null coalescing assignment operators will allow you to retain the first occurring set of digits within a single loop over the data.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/iuPcX))

```
$result = [];
foreach ($array as $i => $number) {
    $sortable = str_split($number);
    sort($sortable);
    $key = implode($sortable);
    $lookup[$key] ??= $i;  // keep $i from first $key
    $result[$lookup[$key]] ??= $number;  // keep first $number from first $key
}
var_export($result);
```

---

If you want a re-indexed result: [Demo](https://3v4l.org/Z4aoP)

```
$result = [];
foreach ($array as $i => $number) {
    $sortable = str_split($number);
    sort($sortable);
    $key = implode($sortable);
    if (!isset($lookup[$key])) {
        $lookup[$key] = true;
        $result[] = $number;
    }
}
var_export($result);
```

*Both of the above scripts enjoy a more efficient/lower time complexity versus Scuzzy's answer because my scripts only use a single loop to do it all.